# pandas MemoryError when left merge two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I need to merge two `df`, `a` and `b`. `a` has about 2.5 million rows, and `b` has about 500k rows. `a` and `b` are read direct from `mongoDB`, converting to `df` using a list, the code is as,

```
 unique_b = b[['id', 'name']]
 unique_b.drop_duplicates()

 a = pd.merge(a, unique_b[['id', 'name']], how='left', on='id')
```

now the `merge` is not only causing `MemoryError`, but taking a very long time (never stops) to processing the merge, in case there is enough memory. I am wondering how to optimise this `pandas` dataframe merge in terms of memory usage and time.

Comment: You may be able to perform this in parts, e.g. by splitting `b` into smaller dataframes, left-joining, then concatenating the results.

Comment: `drop_duplicates` *returns* a new DataFrame. It does not modify the original dataframe. Therefore, to make `unique_b` have unique rows, you must use `unique_b = unique_b.drop_duplicates()`. If you want unique `id`s then use `unique_b = unique_b.drop_duplicates('id')`

Comment: Alternatively, can you perform the actual in a database instead?

Comment: @Evert perform merge in a database?

Comment: Perform the join in a database.

Comment: Unutbu's comment is possibly very relevant. There's also the `inplace` option to `drop_duplicates`.

Comment: @Evert how to split `b` into sub `df` and joins `a`, and then `concat` the results?